# Worth protecting this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

- [What is the exact difference between a latch & a flipflop?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11090/9550)

This question has now received three negative-scored answers from new users (two of which have been deleted to date). Should we protect it? Maybe not necessary since the three bad answers have been spread over five months; or maybe it would be useful because the question seems to have enduring appeal to the bad answerer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When three answers are deleted that would have been blocked by protection, the question is automatically protected.

For general guidelines on protection, see the [FAQ on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question). I don't know why this particular question has attracted several non-answers. I'm in favor of protecting “populist” questions which are likely to attract people with little to say. This is a pretty run-of-the-mill technical question which doesn't warrant such treatment, but nonetheless I think I'll leave the automatic protection in place because that question isn't screaming for a better answer from a drive-by expert.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an instance that the community should be able to handle with ease.

Protection is an excellent measure at putting off newcomers *that have something of value to add*. As such, I'd like to restrict its use to cases of

- high influx of crap
- in a short period of time so that
- (community) moderation is overwhelmed.